# How to switch forms on one page without jquery?

Tags: javascript, forms, select, tabs, internet-explorer-7

This seems like it would be simple, but I can not find a solution anywhere. I need to have either tabs or a  tag with options to change back and forth from one form to another, and have my copy/reset buttons work with whatever form is being used.

Here is an example of a single lonely form of which I need to add about 3 more and keep its format. (my actual page I have has a CSS style formatting and has about 10 more items to fill out):

**UPDATE**: After experimenting with answers so far on here, I have realised that I am also in need of a method to do this that works in IE7.

```
<head>
<title>Form Switching</title>
</head>

<body>

<!-- First Form -->
<form name="data_entry" id="frm" action="#">
  <h2>Form 1</h2>

  <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="3">
    <tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
      <td><textarea name="name" rows="2" cols="30" id="txt_name"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Color:</td>
      <td><select name="color" id="txt_color">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="It is red">Red</option>
          <option value="It is blue">Blue</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Phone Number:</td>
      <td><textarea name="phone" rows="5" cols="30" id="txt_phone"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Distance:</td>
      <td><textarea name="distance" rows="1" cols="30" id="txt_distance"></textarea></td>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
      <!--COPY BUTTON-->
      <td><input type="button" style="font-weight:bold;" name="clipboard_copy" value="Copy" 
onClick="document.data_entry.holdtext.value = 'Name:&nbsp;' + document.data_entry.name.value + '\n' + 'Color:&nbsp;' + document.data_entry.color.value + '\n' + 'Phone:&nbsp;' + document.data_entry.phone.value + '\n' + 'Distance:&nbsp;' + document.data_entry.distance.value; javascript:selectcopy('data_entry.holdtext');javascript:validateForm()"></td>
      <!--RESET BUTTON-->
      <td><input type="button" style="font-weight:bold;" name="reset_form" value="Reset" onClick="this.form.reset();" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>


  <!-- Invisible text box that concatenates all the text boxes into one so they can be copied -->
  <TEXTAREA name="holdtext" readonly="readonly" style="height:1px;width:1px;border:0" ID="holdtext"></TEXTAREA>
</form>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

// ---------- Function to copy text to clipboard ----------
    function selectcopy(fieldid)
    {
    var field=document.getElementById(fieldid) || eval('document.'+fieldid)
    field.select()
    if (field.createTextRange)
    {field.createTextRange().execCommand("Copy")}
    }

</SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

If more Javascript is required, please give me a little more explanation of how to use it, as I am not that experienced with it yet, and I have no way to use jquery as I can only work on this with a company computer that I am not able to download any files to. I am writing my page in notepad, not to mention even after reasearching about jQuery, I still have no idea what it really does.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to **download** jQuery - just put this in your HTML before any JavaScript code that would be using jQuery: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Also, working as a developer on a company computer you can't download any files to, and working in notepad... It may be time to start updating your resume.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### updated with fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f8Qvd/5/

#### update #2 now should work in IE7

This is not too hard without jQuery, though I think you should talk to folks at your job about their file download policy. Anyway, if you want to proceed without jQuery, just add all forms in some divs , and make sure you put them all in a nice container div to make your life easier.

You can also make a nav bar (optionally styled as tabs if you want) with links or clickable divs with some reference to the id of the corresponding form container like:

```
<div id="tab-nav">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="selected" data-container="form-1-container">form1</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-container="form-2-container">form2</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" data-container="form-3-container">form3</a>
</div><!-- #tab-nav -->

<div id="awesome-container">
    <div id="form-1-container">first tab</div>
    <div id="form-2-container">second tab</div>
    <div id="form-3-container">third tab</div>
</div><!-- #awesome-container -->
```

Make sure to give them all unique `id` attributes, and style the initially hidden divs with some good old css:

```
#tab-nav {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
}

#tab-nav a {
    margin-left:25px;
    margin-right:25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#tab-nav a.selected {
    background: #ccd;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#awesome-container {
    width:400px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

#awesome-container div {
    width: 400px;
    height:300px;
    margin:0;
}

#awesome-container #form-1-container {
    background: #ddd;
}
#awesome-container #form-2-container {
    background: #f06;
    display: none;
}
#awesome-container #form-3-container {
    background: #04b;
    display: none;
}
```

My god those tabs are going to be beautiful!

Moving on... to javascript :)

Write a click handler that will deal with the tabs and nav styles. Normally in the absence of jQuery, we would just use `querySelectorAll` to make lists of dom elements to do operations on, but sadly it is not available in IE7, so:

```
(function(){
    var clack = function(e){
        
        // IE is whack, apparently
        var e = e || window.event;
        if( e.srcElement ) {
            e.target = e.srcElement;
        };
        
        var divs = document.getElementById("awesome-container").childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
            if (divs[i].firstChild !== null) { // ignore text nodes
                divs[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        document.getElementById(e.target.getAttribute("data-container")).style.display = "block";
        var links = document.getElementById("tab-nav").childNodes;
        for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
            if (links[j].firstChild !== null) { // ignore text nodes
                links[j].className = "";
            }
        }
        e.target.className = "selected";
    };

    var links = document.getElementById("tab-nav").childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].firstChild !== null) { // you get the idea
            links[i].onclick = clack;
        }
    }
})();
```

That should get you going!

### To see it in action: check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f8Qvd/5/

Comment: Ok, so far it mostly makes sense, but my limited javascript knowledge is halting me from getting it to work. Since I have multiple other functions, would i have to name this function to hide the divs eg: "function switch(e){"? and how do I call it from the <a> link? does the href="javascript:switch();" do that, or would it be a seperate onclick="javascript:" element? Lastly, what do I call the function with? should it be something like javascript:switch(form-1-container) ? Nothing I am trying gets it to work quite right.

Comment: @JustinTennant please see my update. There is also a working fiddle now.

Comment: I feel as if I am doing it right now, but it still doesn't function as it should at all, both on your fiddle example and on my page. When i click links in the fiddle you sent, it says " 'target' is null or not an object " and on myn it says "Object doesn't support this property or method" The line it hangs up on fiddle is "document.getElementById(e.target.getAttribute("data-container")).style.display = "block"; " and myn "var links = document.querySelectorAll("#tab-nav a");
"This may be due to some form of restriction placed on the browsers here, but I've never had javascript not run before.

Comment: @JustinTennant okay, I updated my answer to work with IE8+, If you need to support 7, you can't use querySelectorAll

Comment: @JustinTennant do you care about IE7 for some reason?

Comment: Thanks a ton for the update, I got it to work with IE8 using developer tools, but all the computers here are IE8 locked in IE7 Document mode with IE8 compatability mode stuck on, so they all function as if they were IE7.... So yes, that would be my main issue. Is there any way to do this to work with support for IE7? What could be used instead of the querySelectorAll?

Comment: for IE7 and below you have to iterate over `document.getElementById("awesome-container").childNodes` and make sure not to care about the textNodes in there.

Comment: You are a life saver. I commend you sir for your expertise and kindness!